# Bypassing Client firewall restrictions

Tags: network, firewalls, port-forwarding

Lets suppose we have 2 parties `A`(me) and `B`(participant). I want to communicate with `B` but `B`'s firewall restrictions are not allowing me to communicate with him. Is there any way that I can bypass `B`'s firewall restrictions and communicate with `B`.

**NOTE:**

- A and B don't have any control of each other.
- B cannot modify firewall access policy from his side.

**My Solution:**

As of now, my idea was to use my own proxy and whenever I detect a firewall restriction I will prompt `B` to connect to my proxy do the required port-forwarding.

*Can anyone suggest a better solution for this?*

Comment: Have a look at [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) and [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT) which are designed for exactly this kind of problem. They are used on P2P scenarios like VoiP, WebRTC... . Basically: they employ some tricks to work around specific NAT scenarios and if this fails they fall back to using an external proxy.